# Исключение sonar

Tags: sonarqube

Сделал как описано по этой ссылке, создал файл sonar-project.properties, написал внутри файла sonar.exclusions=src/scss/**/*, но сонар все равно проверяет файлы в папке scss и выдает ошибки в этих файлах, файл создан в корне проекта, пробовал src/scss/*.css, все равно sonarqube индексирует файлы в этой папке, что я делаю не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо:
sonar.exclusions=src/scss/**/*